# How to get next checkbox checked value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I'm trying to implement auto update some of the columns in my sql server database. I have couple of dropboxs and html switches in a form. I'm trying to get the element id and selected value of those elements.

This is the html tag:

```
                                <li class="list-group-item"><b>Market</b><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRecruitingMarket" runat="server" CssClass="pull-right sidebar-controls action">
                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="NA">Select One</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Bangladesh</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Bhutan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Myanmar</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Mauritius</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Nepal</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Maldivs</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Sri Lanka</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><b>Do Not Call</b>
                                    <a class="pull-right">
                                        <label for="chkDoNotCall" class="switch action">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDoNotCall" runat="server" /><span class="slider slider-red round"></span></label></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><b>Do Not Message</b>
                                    <a class="pull-right">
                                        <label for="chkDoNotMessage" class="switch action">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDoNotMessage" runat="server" /><span class="slider slider-red round"></span></label></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><b>Do Not Email</b>
                                    <a class="pull-right">
                                        <label for="chkDoNotEmail" class="switch action">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDoNotEmail" runat="server" /><span class="slider slider-red round"></span></label></a>
                                </li>
```

Now, what i want is when i click on the checkbox, i should be able to get the current checkbox id and the value i.e. true or false.

**Please note**, I'm able to get this for dropdown list right but not working for checkboxes.

Here is my jQuery function for the same.

```
               $(".action").on("change", function () {
                    var elVal = "";
                    if ($(this).hasClass("switch")) {
                        var elmid = $(this).attr("for");
                        elVal = $(this).next("input:checkbox").is(":checked");
                    } else {
                        var elmid = $(this).attr("id");
                        elVal = $(this).val();
                    }
                    alert("Current Element: " + elmid + " | Value: " + elVal);
                });
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your checkboxes have `runat="server"` on them, so whenever you check/uncheck them they will cause a postback and reload the page. Any JS you have running after clicking the checkbox will be aborted.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, yes I know. Surprisingly it is working fine for the dropdown list, just above the checkboxes but not working for checkbox. I have to resolve this for sure. Im not sure is `runat=server` causes any postback or not but there is no `autopostback` for sure.